# Symfony 2.8+ LDAP Roles

Tags: symfony, ldap

I have set up the new LDAP system with symfony 2.8+
[LDAP](http://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-2-8-ldap-component) but I have a problem with the role. It is stated in the documentation that

```
# app/config/security.yml
security:
  # ...
    providers:
        app_users:
            ldap:
                service: app.ldap
                base_dn: dc=example,dc=com
                search_dn: CN=My User,OU=Users,DC=example,DC=com
                search_password: p455w0rd
                filter: (sAMAccountName={username})
                **default_roles: ROLE_USER**
```

But I don't know, how it works. I would like to get the user from my LDAP and then give them roles. Is it possible with the new LDAP Sytem within symfony ?

I previously used IMAG/LdapBundle but you can't set your own roles because of a bug never patched which prevent modifications from beiing saved...

Answer (score 0):

It currently is not really possible in the Symfony LDAP component (as of the most current, 3.1). See [this open issue](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/18803).

However, I maintain a bundle that allows this as you can define roles that map to specific LDAP groups: https://github.com/ldaptools/ldaptools-bundle. Dunno if that will help you, but I tried to give it a lot of different configuration options.